# Facebook WinRT Authentication

Tags: facebook, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am using WinRT's WebAuthenticationBroker to attempt to connect to Facebook over OAuth. When I do this I get back a page that says: An error occurred. Please try again later.

I am wondering how I can get the details of what the error is so that I can fix it. Any info on debugging Facebook would be great.